# representing data on world map using python

Tags: python, google-maps, geodjango, world-map

I have a data base which represent some contents according to each city and state. I want to design an interface where, when user clicks on a city/state in the map it represents the list of contents that I have in the data base (as per the city/state). Since I am a python programmer I am looking for something in python. I am aware of Geo Django, but as of now I don't want to get into the details. I want to know if there is any other simple, open source code that exists, which can be used to just put my data and modify a little for visual representation.